# Can't profile an Azure worker role

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, profiling

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2010 Premium's built-in profiling for Azure and am having trouble. What I'm doing seems to follow tutorials but my "Enable Profiling" checkbox is grayed out. I'm using Windows Azure Tools 1.8 (Oct 2012) and VS2010 Premium running on Windows 8 x64 as Admin. I also have RDP enabled. My understanding is that I've satisfied all of the requirements for profiling.

The only way I know to manage these profiles is to right-click on my Cloud project (the one with `.csdef` and `.cscfg` files), click "Publish...", and work with the settings in there. Under the "Advanced" tab, the "Enable Profiling" checkbox is grayed out, so I can't even get to the Profiling settings link.

Any idea what the deal is?

Comment: Is your project .net 4.5 based?

Comment: ... which actually probably means 4.5, so yes. I hate that damned replacement upgrade...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on this for now and am just using dotTrace for remote profiling. I outlined the steps to get this working [here on this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15102944/294863). If somebody has an answer specific to the original question, I'm still very interested in that and will gladly transfer the selected answer to that if you post it. Until then, this solution works well enough for me...